# Magento onepage link adds hash(#) to current url when clicked on any edit link?

Tags: magento, paypal, checkout

Well, I am integrating pay-pal express checkout to magento for the first time.

Here is the URL of my store

http://missymtoyz.com/missymtoyz/magento_admin_test/checkout/onepage/

When I click any of the edit link, it add hash(#) at the end of url, how could it work as it works in default theme?

Comment: You have not customized properly properly. Please replace with default and then customize again. And I think your customization will work if you are register one. Please check

Comment: Well I changed my theme  from  admin >> system >> design >> to default and things work. but when i changed back to my theme, it gives same problem. Are there any other options to be set for properly customizing the template ?

Comment: yes just take backup of files from you theme and replace it wuth default files and implement you changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've copied the `href` from the base default theme - and have confirmed it's also a `#` on base default, you've probably missed some Javascript that is bound to the link. I would have another thorough look through the base default theme to figure out the exact actions triggered by the link.

Comment: Jquery and Prototype caused this problem, So dollar sign ($) is overridden by JQuery. However, it should always represent Prototype.js. So I used jQuery.noConflict() and just change the ordering of jquery to be included first in page.xml then adding all the default Magento JS files.